# "Try Ubuntu" requires login? O.o

Tags: login

First time ever using Ubuntu so just wanted to try it.

I downloaded the image and burnt it, booted it, and selected "Try Ubuntu". After a few mins, it loads the desktop but requires a login? O.o

I've downloaded "Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS" (Desktop, 64bit) from the official server and the checksums match.

I've tried "ubuntu", "lubuntu", "xubuntu", "xbuntu", all with blank passwords.

Any help please?

i.imgur.com/cCvg8Rv.jpg

Comment: could you support with a screenshot ?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/cCvg8Rv.jpg

Comment: Try to : control+alt+f1 and see if it requires a username, pass.. if it didn't you can sudo and create a user.. otherwise i suggest re-install from a guide..

Comment: When I hit those keys it went to a black screen with a doezen lines all saying "Authentication failute". I followed the guide from the official website, it's all straight forward?

Comment: I'm actually really weirded all out that you're facing these problems.. 
I think you must've done something wrong...
Try to reinstall if you still face problems I'll try to personally help with it..
But try to download it from scratch from the official ubuntu website..

Comment: Ok thankyou. I will have to try tomorrow, but will reply back here.

Comment: Welcome! happy to help..
Let me know if you need anything further from there.